# Can I farm Lei in Resident Evil Village?

Tags: resident-evil-village

I’m wrapping up my play through of Resident Evil Village and I want to fully upgrade my guns. I don’t have quite enough money but I’ve killed and looted everything accessible to me so I’m not sure how to get more.

I think I would have been able to afford the final few upgrades, but I missed some treasures and now it’s too late to go back for it. The enemies I’ve defeated don’t seem to be respawning either.

How can I farm Lei in Resident Evil Village?

Comment: I've played it quite a bit and I don't think there is a way to farm Lei in a single playthrough. However, if you start a New Game+ game you'll carry over your Lei, inventory and a few other things so you can farm it through repeat plays.

Comment: Having started my third playthrough now, I'm starting to think you're right. Post it as an answer

Comment: Don't have the time right now to make it a proper answer. FWIW though it _might_ be possible to farm Lei in the first Urias encounter (but not really worth it). I'm not sure of what the criteria are for the battle ending though.

Comment: It's time based. There are achievements for killing the Urias, or 30 lycans during the encounter, but they'll keep spawning. Speedrunners have already figured out all you need to do is survive for ~3 minutes